# Task.WhenAll for ValueTask

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, valuetask

Is there an equivalent of `Task.WhenAll` accepting `ValueTask`?

I can work around it using

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(t => t.AsTask()))
```

This will be fine if they're all wrapping a `Task` but it will force the useless allocation of a `Task` object for real `ValueTask`.

Comment: `Task.WhenAll(tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompletedSuccessfully).Select(t => t.AsTask()))`

Comment: Şafak Gür's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63141544/11178549) should be the accepted one IMHO!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

By design, no. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1): *(link updated)*

> A method may return an instance of this value type when it's likely that the result of its operation will be available synchronously, and when it's expected to be invoked so frequently that the cost of allocating a new Task<TResult> for each call will be prohibitive.
>
> …
>
> For example, consider a method that could return either a Task<TResult> with a cached task as a common result or a ValueTask<TResult>. If the consumer of the result wants to use it as a Task<TResult> in a method like WhenAll or WhenAny, the ValueTask<TResult> must first be converted to a Task<TResult> using `AsTask()`, leading to an allocation that would have been avoided if a cached Task<TResult> had been used in the first place.

Comment: While it's good to know it's by design, I dont see any reasoning given. It's not clear what is an easy way to cache tasks other than implementing it ourselves. Had `Task.WhenAny` and `Task.WhenAll` had overloads for `ValueTask`s things would have been lot easier.

Comment: This answer [may have changed](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2019/08/prefer-valuetask-to-task-always-and.html)

Comment: @Nathan I have taken to using ValueTask in my APIs, after considering the caveats mentioned by @marc-gravell in that link and others. But there is still no equivalent of `Task.WhenAll`...

Comment: @stuartd, agreed - just pointing out that the docs around the subject are... ageing :)

Answer (score 20):

Unless there is something I'm missing, we should be able to just await all the tasks in a loop:

```cs
public static async ValueTask<T[]> WhenAll<T>(params ValueTask<T>[] tasks)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tasks);
    if (tasks.Length == 0)
        return Array.Empty<T>();

    var results = new T[tasks.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        results[i] = await tasks[i].ConfigureAwait(false);

    return results;
}
```

**Allocations**
Awaiting a `ValueTask` that is completed synchronously shouldn't cause a `Task` to be allocated. So the only "extra" allocation happening here is of the array we use for returning the results.

**Order**
Order of the returned items are the same as the order of the given tasks that produce them.

**Concurrency**
Even though it looks like we execute the tasks sequentially, this is not really the case as the tasks are already started (i.e. are in a hot state) when this method is called. Therefore we only wait as long as the longest task in the array (thanks Sergey for asking about this in the comments).

**Exceptions**
When a task throws an exception, the above code would stop waiting for the rest of the tasks and just throw. If this is undesirable, we could do:

```cs
public static async ValueTask<T[]> WhenAll<T>(params ValueTask<T>[] tasks)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(tasks);
    if (tasks.Length == 0)
        return Array.Empty<T>();

    // We don't allocate the list if no task throws
    List<Exception>? exceptions = null;

    var results = new T[tasks.Length];
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        try
        {
            results[i] = await tasks[i].ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions ??= new(tasks.Length);
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }

    return exceptions is null
        ? results
        : throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

**Extra considerations**

- We can have this as an extension method.
- We can have overloads that accept `IEnumerable<ValueTask<T>>` and `IReadOnlyList<ValueTask<T>>` for wider compatibility.

Sample signatures:

```cs
// There are some collections (e.g. hash-sets, queues/stacks,
// linked lists, etc) that only implement I*Collection interfaces
// and not I*List ones, but A) we're not likely to have our tasks
// in them and B) even if we do, IEnumerable accepting overload
// below should handle them. Allocation-wise; it's a ToList there
// vs GetEnumerator here.
public static async ValueTask<T[]> WhenAll<T>(
    IReadOnlyList<ValueTask<T>> tasks)
{
    // Our implementation above.
}

// ToList call below ensures that all tasks are initialized, so
// calling this with an iterator wouldn't cause the tasks to run
// sequentially.
public static ValueTask<T[]> WhenAll<T>(
    IEnumerable<ValueTask<T>> tasks)
{
    return WhenAll(tasks?.ToList());
}

// Arrays already implement IReadOnlyList<T>, but this overload
// is still useful because the `params` keyword allows callers 
// to pass individual tasks like they are different arguments.
public static ValueTask<T[]> WhenAll<T>(
    params ValueTask<T>[] tasks)
{
    return WhenAll(tasks as IReadOnlyList<ValueTask<T>>);
}
```

Theodor in the comments mentioned the approach of having the result array/list passed as an argument, so *our* implementation would be free of all extra allocations, but the caller will still have to create it. This could make sense if they batch await tasks, which sounds like a fairly specialized scenario to me, but for completeness' sake:

```cs
// Arrays implement `IList<T>`
public static async ValueTask WhenAll<T>(ValueTask<T>[] source, IList<T> target)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(target);

    if (source.Length != target.Count)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Source and target lengths must match",
            nameof(target));

    List<Exception>? exceptions = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        try
        {
            target[i] = await source[i].ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions ??= new(source.Length);
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }

    if (exceptions is not null)
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

Comment: Very nice! I deleted my answer because yours is superior. I think that your last version of `WhenAll`, the one that throws an `AggregateException`, has the behavior that most developers would expect.

Comment: Your code would work slowly, because you're awaiting the tasks one by one. For example, your have a hundred of tasks where each task completes in one hundredth of a second synchronously or in one second asynchronously. If 50 of 100 tasks happen to be asynchronous, your implementation will spend 50.5 seconds. `Task.WhenAll` would spend 1 second. `Task.WhenAll` != awaitning in a loop. You shouldn't wait for the previous task to complete in order to launch the next.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov - `Your code would work slowly, because you're awaiting the tasks one by one` - Yes, but I'm not starting them one by one; .NET tasks start running when you create them, they don't wait for you to await them. This means when this method is called, the tasks that are passed are already running (i.e. in a hot state) concurrently. Therefore we only wait as long as the longest task in the array.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov - Here's a quick sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DpWdC0

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. I was thinking about processing `IEnumerable<ValueTask>` where it would be an issue.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean - If we accepted a parameter of `IEnumerable<ValueTask<T>>` instead of `ValueTask<T>[]`, people could pass lazy enumerables (e.g. using [yield](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)) which would cause the tasks to be initialized _as we're iterating them_ - in that case a `.ToList()` call before we start our loop would be useful. But yeah, we accept an array in this example, so we don't have that problem.

Comment: For a zero allocations solution, it is possible to pass the `results` array as argument like this: `WhenAll<T>(T[] results, params ValueTask<T>[] tasks)`. This makes sense only if the `WhenAll` is called repeatedly in a loop, with the same number of arguments each time. In this case you can create the `results` array once, and reuse it for all the iterations of the loop.

Comment: **Wrong**
A task may not be started at all if one has neither awaited for it or executed Task.WaitAny/Task.WaitAll. Methods like Tasks.WaitAny exists for a reason!! "awaiting" one by one, in practice one is forcing an order of execution and losing the performance  of asynchrounous flow.

Comment: Those methods exist so that you know when the tasks end, not so that you can start them - they’re already started if obtained properly (i.e. via Task.Run, Task.Factory.StartNew, or by the async method state machine). You’re doing it wrong if you’re using the Task ctor and pass around unstarted tasks, as I doubt even the .NET methods you named would act as you expect with them. It would be absurd if the receiver of a promise object would be expected to fulfil that promise (in any sane language). ValueTasks have slightly different semantics but the fact that they are created hot is just the same

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a WhenAny() version of this?

Comment: GuildOfCalamity hit the jackpot: IMHO, that's exactly why no off-the-shelf support for WhenAll/WhenAny is an issue - implementing WhenAll is relatively trivial compared to WhenAny. As all tasks are assumed to be hot, WhenAll can just wait for them one by one in any order, whatever happens it will eventually be bound to wait as long as the longest task take to complete.  But for WhenAny, we just can't. If we wait on any single of N tasks given, we have 1/Nth prob to wait too long and get wrong result :) ATM I dont see how we can write it for ValueTasks with no-allocations..

Answer (score 9):

As @stuartd pointed out, it is not supported by design, I had to implement this manually:

```
public static async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<T>> WhenAll<T>(this IEnumerable<ValueTask<T>> tasks)
{
    var results = new List<T>();
    var toAwait = new List<Task<T>>();

    foreach (var valueTask in tasks)
    {
        if (valueTask.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            results.Add(valueTask.Result);
        else
            toAwait.Add(valueTask.AsTask());
    }

    results.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(toAwait).ConfigureAwait(false));

    return results;
}
```

Of course this will help only in high throughput and high number of `ValueTask` as it adds some other overheads.

NOTE: As @StephenCleary pointed out, this does not keep the order as `Task.WhenAll` does, if it is required it can be easily changed to implement it.

Comment: The collection of results is also potentially in a different order than the original value tasks.

Comment: @StephenCleary took that into account, but I did not mean it as a precise replacement for `Task.WhenAll`, it can be easily fixed though.

Comment: The irony of using `ValueTask` to reduce allocations, yet having to resort to allocations anyways to use it.

Comment: I'd go so far as to say that using a `Task` in this scenario is probably more efficient than using helper methods like these, which do not merely allocate an instance of a type, they allocate multiple arrays of them. My guess is that this method performs worse than just using `Task` in many/most cases, so I'd advice anyone to measure the performance of either approach before choosing what to use.

Answer (score -4):

I'm using this extension method:

```
internal static class ValueTaskExtensions
{
    public static Task WhenAll(this IEnumerable<ValueTask> tasks)
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(v => v.AsTask()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the question as calling AsTask() causes an allocation, thus making the use of ValueTask useless.

Answer (score -6):

Tried to do some optimization, result returned in correct order and correct exception handling.

```
public static ValueTask<T[]> WhenAll<T>(IEnumerable<ValueTask<T>> tasks)
    {
        var list = tasks.ToList();
        var length = list.Count;
        var result = new T[length];
        var i = 0;

        for (; i < length; i ++)
        {
            if (list[i].IsCompletedSuccessfully)
            {
                result[i] = list[i].Result;
            }
            else
            {
                return WhenAllAsync();
            }
        }

        return new ValueTask<T[]>(result);

        async ValueTask<T[]> WhenAllAsync()
        {
            for (; i < length; i ++)
            {
                try
                {
                    result[i] = await list[i];
                }
                catch
                {
                    for (i ++; i < length; i ++)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await list[i];
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            // ignored
                        }
                    }

                    throw;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Triple-nested loops are totally unnecessary, and because all are using the same loop control variable it's never going to work.

Comment: @BenVoigt, It is not triple nested loops. And please learn the basics of for(;;) statement. Here is link
https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.php

Comment: There's a loop inside a catch inside a loop inside a function call inside a loop.  That's a triple-nested loop, even if the shared control variable means that only a single pass is made through the sequence.  It would be so much better and clearer without the nesting, just step 1: save results of leading already-completed tasks, step 2: await remaining tasks saving results, step 3: in case of exception, wait for other tasks to resolve ignoring results (because there is no return value when control leaves the function via exception)

Comment: too many unnecessary allocations