# Use await all the time (`await x; await x; ....`) vs .Result after the first await (`await x; x.Result; x.Result; ....`)?

Tags: c#, async-await

Are there any differences between the following two code snippets?

1: Use `await` all the time

```
await Task.WhenAll(x, y);
var a = await x;
var b = await y;
(await x).f();
(await y).g();
```

2: Use `.Result` after the first `await`.

```
await Task.WhenAll(x, y);
var a = x.Result;
var b = y.Result;
x.Result.f();
y.Result.g();
```

Comment: Were you intending to use `a` and `b` in those snippets? Otherwise they are completely redundant.

Comment: Not very clear. In the first code you're awaiting multiple time the same task, i.e. you first wait `x` in the `WhenAll`, then again right below, and a third time when calling `f`. The second code awaits `x` only once.

Comment: @MarioVernari - Which doesn't change the semantics of the code. I think that's what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Enigmativity still I don't catch what he's actually asking. To me, the two codes behaves differently, from a generic perspective (what really x and y does?)

Comment: I've updated the question. @Enigmativity is right, I want to know if there is any semantic or performance difference.

Comment: To me, they COULD be different. As an example, consider x (and y) as "insert a new record in the table". The first code inserts three records, whereas the second only once. Of course, from the `f` call perspective, there's no difference. Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - You complicate the question with the redundant `a` and `b`. You should remove them or use them. I vote use them.

Comment: @MarioVernari - No, it doesn't. It only runs the task once. You can `await` multiple times, but the task only runs once.

Comment: It's  like `x = 2 + 3;`. You can use `2 + 3` everywhere in your code, but it makes more sense to use `x`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, the lines which use `a` and `b` are omitted. They are used right after the lines shown in the question.

Comment: @ca9163d9 - You should post complete code in your question. You just make it confusing otherwise. Give each line a purpose.

Comment: Catchy! I just made shameful my day! thank you everybody for pointing me this.

Comment: I'm assuming `x` and `y` are `Task` and not `ValueTask`, otherwise it would be a completely different thing in both cases (errors in both as you can only access the result at most, once).

Comment: @JeffMercado [there is no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689327/task-whenall-for-valuetask) `Task.WhenAll` for `ValueTask`s. The `x` and `y` are certainly `Task`s

Comment: @TheodorZoulias ah is that right? well I learned something new :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will not be any behavioral difference between the two as both tasks are guaranteed to be finished after the `Task.WhenAll`.

The compiler seems not to be aware of this and generates a slightly more complicated state machine in the first case (I verified this by looking at the generated IL, see [here for a proof](https://sharplab.io/#gist:c8472e8c318be4b4b2333e83d384d241)).

However, this will hardly make any noticable performance difference.

(Stylistically, the multiple await would be preferrable to me as seeing a `.Result` in async code makes all sort of alarm bells ring).

**Update:** As Stephen Cleary explained in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623120/await-on-a-completed-task-same-as-task-result), `await x` and `x.Result` will behave differently (different Exception type) if the task failed. But this does not apply here because any failing task would have already made `await Task.WhenAll(...)` throw an exception.

Comment: *"[...] there will be a behavior difference (different Exception type) if the task failed."* -- I don't think so. The `await Task.WhenAll(x, y);` will expose the error of either task, right there.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias oh, yes, of course you are right. The exception will be thrown already there so any later possible behavior differences between await x and x.Result do not matter.